# Symfony 3 notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null

Tags: php, symfony, frameworks, command, runtime-error

I'm working with Symfony 3.4 with XAMPP,
after i installed the project with composer, i wrote the command:

```
php bin/console cache:clear
```

then i received this notice and so the cache clear isn't happening:

```
In DocParser.php line 967: 
Notice: Trying to access array offset on value of type null
```

I tried to use the command `composer update` and it didn't work

Also i deleted my XAMPP and downgraded to the version where the version PHP 5.4 is used and it didn't work either,

so what other solutions can be ?
Thanks.

Answer (score 1):

its PHP version Compatibility issue , check version php in composer.json if it